# Slightly noncommutative Nakayama's lemma?

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, noncommutative-rings, nonnoetherian, group-algebras

Nakayama's lemma asserts the following. If $R $ is a commutative ring with an element $s$, and $M$ is a finitely generated module such that $sM = M$, then there exists $r \in R$ such that $rM =0$ and $r-1 $ belongs to the ideal generated by $s$.

Is the following known (or false)?

**Question**: Suppose that $R$ is a an algebra over the reals (or a ring) that is finitely generated, and is prime (or even stronger, has no zero divisors) and satisfies a polynomial identity. Suppose $s$ is a central non-zero divisor of $R$ that is not a unit, and $M$ is a submodule of a principal left $R$-module, with the property that $sM = M$. *Does there exist nonzero $r \in R$ such that $rM = 0$*?

Finitely generated prime PI algebras and rings, although they are close to being noetherian, need not be noetherian; so that we cannot conclude that $M$ is finitely generated as an $R$-module. In my context (described more informally below), there does not seem to be a way to show that $M$ is finitely generated.

*Motivation* This problem stems from a question on  random walks on countably infinite (discrete) groups. Let $G$ be a group and let $f$ be an element of the group algebra over the reals whose nonzero coefficients are positive, and such that the support generates $G$ as a semigroup. Repeated left multiplication by $f$ on ${\bf R}G$ corresponds to an (unnormalized) random walk on $G$, and we can take the direct limit, viewed as a partially ordered real vector space, with various additional properties.

There is a natural version of Jacobson's conjecture (the same one which is solved by the usual Nakayama's lemma, described above), in this context. When $G$ is right orderable, the corresponding result (the RW version of Jacobson's conjecture) is true. However, when we look at a torsion-free abelian-by-finite group (that is not right orderable---such groups exist, see Passman's book), the usual methods don't work, and we have to resort to questions such as the one given here (an affirmative answer to which would solve this version of Jacobson's conjecture). One problem is that the rings that appear (even in the abelian-by-finite case) to be relevant to the problem are generally not noetherian!

Comment: References for the failure of the naive version of Nakayama's lemma in the non-commutative setting: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/888494/one-sided-version-of-the-nakayama-lemma or Remark 1.10 in https://arxiv.org/pdf/1507.01213.pdf

Comment: @ TomekKania For noetherian PI rings (more generally, fully bounded noetherian), there are affirmative results for the Jacobson conjecture; for other noetherian rings, the result is false. The PI hypothesis is crucial (and any subring of the group algebra satisfies a PI, provided the group is abelian by finite).